# Multiple defaults for zend_form_select

Tags: zend-form

Having a Zend_Form with a Zend_Form_Element_Select on it, i can set ONE option selected with setDefault. But how can i select multiple items on that element, like

```
$this->setDefaults(array('groups' => 5, 'groups', 7));
```

But this will only select the option with value 7, option with value 5 is still NOT selected :(
($this is zend_form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `Zend_Form_Element_Select` element can only have one value. If you want a multiselect element, you can use `Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect`. To set the defaults, you can use either:

```
$this->setDefaults(array('elementName' => array(5, 7)));
```

or

```
$this->setDefault('elementName', array(5, 7));
```